# Can I travel to Hungary after being deported from UK?

Tags: study, hungary, residency, nigerian-citizens

I'm a Nigerian citizen who lived in the UK for 13years with indefinite leave to remain. I got deported for drug offences and I'm now planning to further my education in hungary.
My girlfriend is hungarian and we are also planning to get married.

My question is can I travel to Hungary to study, and what are the chances of me getting a permanent residence in hungary if I marry my girlfriend?

Comment: Please edit your question to bring it back to topic and use the 'reopen' vote to have it voted upon.

Answer (score 1):

Hungary is part of the Schengen area, so you'll need a Schengen visa to visit (assuming you're not already in a Schengen area country, in that case you can travel without a visa). If you intend to study there, you should apply for a student visa.

UK is outside of the Schengen zone, so your immigration status there is not relevant. However, being deported from anywhere will not improve your chances of a Schengen visa (in case UK authorities share that data with the EU or it is visible in your passport).